# How to remove this error in Android Studio 2.2?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new in running android studio on Ubuntu. Every time, when I try to build grade. this error shows Kindly tell me the solution of this problem.
[Error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o055L.png)

Comment: try to delete build folder and clean and rebuild.

Comment: try to clean re build project. in res folder check ic_launcer.png file also.

Comment: try to keep your project path short and then clean and run again

Comment: How can I keep the path short @AbhayBohra?

Comment: @usamamw141 :for example keep your project in e or d drive location and then try to clean and run project

Comment: I mentioned that I am running Ubuntu, where should I keep my  folders? in root or somewhere else? @AbhayBohra